# I have successfully installed magento in wamp, but land page admin pannel is not working

Tags: magento, loading

I Installed Megento in WampServer. I installed several time and it shows perfect. " I have installed Magento perfectly". But problem is Admin link is not working. even //localhost/Magento/ is not perfectly loaded. [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRiwS.png)

[image]

I have above files in my magento folder. Can you please help me regarding this.

Best,
Haniar

Comment: check you logs in `var/log` folder

Comment: Ya, I have two .log file. One Debug.log and another is install.log.
what I need to do now ?

Comment: no, they should be `exception.log` and `system.log`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Well part of the problem is probably that Magento doesn't let you have an admin page without a period in it.  Try changing your hostname from localhost to localhost.dev (or something else if you prefer)

Answer (score 0):

As I was having the same problem as you do, I installed my local magento using 127.0.0.1 as domain url and it then worked. This also pairs with what user2957454 says